# using DiagnosticMonitor from nodejs in Azure

Tags: node.js, azure

I wonder if people had any luck configuring DiagnosticMonitor in a nodejs app running in Azure?  The http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/common-tasks/performance-profiling/ link is under nodejs...but shows C# sample code.

Any hints/sample code are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a better way to configure Windows Azure Diagnostics, it's through the [diagnostics.wadcfg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg604918.aspx) file. You simply configure the diagnostics through this XML file and include it in your package.

[David Hardin](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidhardin/archive/2011/03/29/configuring-wad-via-the-diagnostics-wadcfg-config-file.aspx) explains the advantages in a blog post:

> I instead recommend using diagnostics.wadcfg for all role types to
>   perform the the majority of the configuration and only configure via
>   code when required, such as when using a custom performance counter. 
>   This will allow WAD to capture diagnostics prior to OnStart’s
>   execution plus it is easier to maintain a config file than code.

Comment: Thanks; it seems it should work but i must be missing something:  I tried this with a vanilla C# worker role and it worked great.  However, can't get it working with nodejs... I've deployed  diagnostics.wadcfg to the F:\approot folder next to other files, i've added "Diagnostics" import to the definitions file but don't see perf counters being published :(